# How to transform this array in a json?

Tags: json, cakephp, highcharts

I have this relation `Company`hasMany `Branch`

And using `$this->Company->find('all')` output  this:

```
(int) 1 => array(
    'Company' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'nome' => 'Somov',
        'diretores' => 'Marcelo, Carl'
    ),
    'Branch' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'nome' => 'Serra',
            'rua' => 'Rua teste 2 exttttt',
            'numero' => '22',
            'estado' => 'ES',
            'cidade' => 'Etc',
            'cep' => '',
            'responsavel' => '',
            'company_id' => '4',
            'cnpj' => ''
        )
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'Company' => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'nome' => 'Soimpex',
        'diretores' => ''
    ),
    'Branch' => array()
)
```

)

I want to transform this in a json like this to use with Highchart:

```
[{
            name: NAME OF COMPANY (nome),
            data: NUMBER OF BRANCHS

        }, {
            name: NAME OF COMPANY (nome),
            data: NUMBER OF BRANCHS

        }]
```

How I do this convertion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a json object with only one result.

If we use previous example, can be done like this:

```
$arr = $this->Company->find('all'); // fetch the array
$arr1 = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $tmp = array();

    $tmp['name'] = $value['Company']['nome'];
    $tmp['data'] = count($value['Branch']);

    $arr1[] = $tmp;
}
return json_encode($arr1);
```

Comment: Hi, count method is returning an integer so you should not see result from count as string. Anyway, maybe you modify it after you called count method. You can cast a string into a integer in php, e.g. $string = (int) $string;

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from Posts limit 20"); 

 $response = array();
 $posts = array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
  { 
    $title=$row['title']; 
    $url=$row['url']; 

    $posts[] = array('title'=> $title, 'url'=> $url);

  } 

    $response['posts'] = $posts;

    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
    fclose($fp);


  ?>
```

This will generate a file called results.json file where your php file is stored on your online server, taking url and title variables from your MySQL db, you can change the variable names to what you want to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea is about like this

```
$arr=$this->Company->find('all'); // fetch the array
$arr1=array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $arr1['name']=$value['Company']['nome'];
    //some more manual transform to desire format
}
return json_encode($arr1);
```